# Importing System.Management.Automation with Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

For reasons, I need to use PowerShell to get information about the computer's IP.  Therefore, I tried using `System.Management.Automation` along with NugetForUnity, but VS keeps saying that `The type or namespace name 'Automation' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Management' (are you missing an assembly reference?)`  I know for a **fact** that I have installed the package, but I have not gotten anywhere with this project for the past 4 hours.  Does anybody have any advice? Here is my code:

```cs
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class getLocation : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        //https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1206308/Powershell-commands-from-Csharp
        //Modified by @alex#6555
        using (var ps = PowerShell.Create())
        {
            ps.AddCommand("curl");
            ps.AddArgument("ipinfo.io");
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

If anybody knows what to do, some pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need to call PS to run `curl` for this task? What keeps you from simply using a [HttpWebRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest?view=net-6.0)?

Comment: ... and there's also [UnityWebRequest](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Get.html) so it really looks like you are way overcomplicating things here.